# Interpreting the output of splitting with white spaces

Tags: java, string, split

How do we interpret the output of the flollowing execution

```
String s="   "  //3 white spaces
String arr[]=s.split(" ")   // output arr has no elements, same is the case on using \\s+ as the delimiter.
```

If we do the same in python, the op is `['' ,'' ,'']` which is understood.

How does java split the above and why is there no element in arr ?

Comment: Try `s.split("\\s", -1)`. Read about it in the [`String#split(String, int)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)). The relevant part for you at the moment is *and trailing empty strings will be discarded.*

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."

You may prefer to use `s.split(" ", -1)` if you want trailing empty strings.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)